# Can you put SKAction inside an if Statement?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, skaction

Here is what I really want the argument to be but it wouldn't work. what is the right way of doing this?
any idea?

```
if (targetWithinRange == NO) {

      SKAction *move = [SKAction moveToX:-30 duration:1]; //Warning Unused Variable 'move'

}else{ //or if the target is within rang then go and hit the target

      SKAction *move = [SKAction moveTo:(CGPointMake(target.position.x, target.position.y)) duration:1];//Warning Unused Variable 'move'
 }    



 SKAction *lookingForTheTarget = [SKAction sequence:@[someAction,move,anotherAction]];

[ourSprite runAction:lookingForTheTarget];
```

Comment: This is a scope issue. The answer points that out, but you should make a point to learn more about scope now, or you will run into many more similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of move is only in the `if` statement.

You should probably move it outside of the `if`:

```
SKAction *move;
if (targetWithinRange == NO) {
    move = ...
}
else {
    move = ...
}
```